# run a web site on localhost using docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I did a backup of my web from remote server to my desktop and also a backup to mysql and I want to run my web on docker I already created a docker-compose.yml file. but I didn't find a way how to run it.

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

after I do docker-compose up. I get errors. All I did is backup to my web and to database and I create docker-compose.yml

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/web/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "80:80"
  mysql:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/database/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: airinuit
      MYSQL_DATABASE: airinuit
      MYSQL_USER: airinuit
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: airinuit
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  my-db:
```

docker file for database : `FROM vsamov/mysql-5.1.73`

docker file for web : `FROM alterway/php:5.3-apache`

that all what I did and I know that I miss something I should do but I don't know what.

this is no error `docker-compose up` I get :

```
myweb_web_1 is up-to-date
myweb_mysql_1 is up-to-date
Attaching to myweb_web_1, myweb_mysql_1
web_1    | [Sat Sep 14 22:36:58 2019] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.3.29 configured -- resuming normal operations
web_1    | [Sat Sep 14 23:36:47 2019] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
web_1    | [Sat Sep 14 23:36:51 2019] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.3.29 configured -- resuming normal operations
web_1    | [Sat Sep 14 23:38:00 2019] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
web_1    | [Sat Sep 14 23:38:03 2019] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.3.29 configured -- resuming normal operations
web_1    | [Sun Sep 15 01:04:43 2019] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
web_1    | [Sun Sep 15 01:11:31 2019] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.3.29 configured -- resuming normal operations
web_1    | [Sun Sep 15 01:24:13 2019] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
web_1    | [Sun Sep 15 03:03:00 2019] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.3.29 configured -- resuming normal operations
mysql_1  | 190914 17:48:43 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysql_1  | 190914 17:48:43  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
mysql_1  | 190914 17:48:43  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mysql_1  | 190914 17:48:43  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
mysql_1  | 190914 17:48:43 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
mysql_1  | 190914 17:48:43 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mysql_1  | Version: '5.1.73'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
mysql_1  | 190914 18:12:40 [Note] mysqld: Normal shutdown
mysql_1  | 
mysql_1  | 190914 18:12:40 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
mysql_1  | 190914 18:12:42  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
mysql_1  | 190914 18:12:44  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 44233
mysql_1  | 190914 18:12:44 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
mysql_1  | 
mysql_1  | 190914 18:21:04 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysql_1  | 190914 18:21:04  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
mysql_1  | 190914 18:21:04  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mysql_1  | 190914 18:21:04  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
mysql_1  | 190914 18:21:04 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
mysql_1  | 190914 18:21:04 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mysql_1  | Version: '5.1.73'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
mysql_1  | 190914 22:19:06 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysql_1  | 190914 22:19:06  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
mysql_1  | 190914 22:19:06  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mysql_1  | 190914 22:19:06  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
mysql_1  | 190914 22:19:06 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
mysql_1  | 190914 22:19:06 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mysql_1  | Version: '5.1.73'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
mysql_1  | 190914 22:36:06 [Note] mysqld: Normal shutdown
mysql_1  | 
mysql_1  | 190914 22:36:06 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
mysql_1  | 190914 22:36:06  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
mysql_1  | 190914 22:36:08  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 44233
mysql_1  | 190914 22:36:08 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
mysql_1  | 
mysql_1  | 190914 22:36:57 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysql_1  | 190914 22:36:57  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
mysql_1  | 190914 22:36:57  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mysql_1  | 190914 22:36:57  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
mysql_1  | 190914 22:36:57 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
mysql_1  | 190914 22:36:57 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mysql_1  | Version: '5.1.73'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
mysql_1  | 190915  1:04:43 [Note] mysqld: Normal shutdown
mysql_1  | 
mysql_1  | 190915  1:04:43 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
mysql_1  | 190915  1:04:45  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
mysql_1  | 190915  1:04:49  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 1447103275
mysql_1  | 190915  1:04:49 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
mysql_1  | 
mysql_1  | 190915  1:11:31 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysql_1  | 190915  1:11:31  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
mysql_1  | 190915  1:11:31  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mysql_1  | 190915  1:11:31  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 1447103275
mysql_1  | 190915  1:11:31 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
mysql_1  | 190915  1:11:31 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mysql_1  | Version: '5.1.73'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
mysql_1  | 190915  1:24:13 [Note] mysqld: Normal shutdown
mysql_1  | 
mysql_1  | 190915  1:24:13 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
mysql_1  | 190915  1:24:13  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
mysql_1  | 190915  1:24:17  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 1447103275
mysql_1  | 190915  1:24:17 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
mysql_1  | 
mysql_1  | 190915  3:03:00 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysql_1  | 190915  3:03:00  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
mysql_1  | 190915  3:03:00  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mysql_1  | 190915  3:03:00  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 1447103275
mysql_1  | 190915  3:03:00 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
mysql_1  | 190915  3:03:00 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mysql_1  | Version: '5.1.73'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: better to post errors logs, how one can help without dockerfile or errors logs?

Comment: "I get errors": I don't see any errors. But if what you have posted is complete then the web container does not have access to any web files. Did you forget to mount them in?

Comment: I forget to add the error I'm getting so I did add the error message